# Is there any rule for ordering CSS rules?

Tags: css

Is there any rule to order CSS rules? Normally whenever I edit CSS on [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), it re-orders the CSS while on chrome developer tools it remains as-is. While the [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=18359)  orders them in completely different manner.

This is what happens in Firebug

[While Editing](http://prntscr.com/15rq4b)

[After Editing](http://prntscr.com/15rq59)

Comment: You can't always reorder the rules as when two rules have the same weight the last specified applies.

Comment: I don't see what your questions means. A rule to order css rules **where** ? Who/what software should apply this rule you're looking for ?

Comment: @dystroy , I think with *rule* he's asking about (the existence of) *Best Practices* on how to declare CSS rules inside a plain .css file.

Comment: @AndreaLigios OK, might be that. So I don't think it's constructive enough for SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the best practices for writing maintainable CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652904/what-are-the-best-practices-for-writing-maintainable-css)

Comment: The example does not show a reordering of rules. It shows how Firebug inserts a new *declaration* relative to existing declarations within a rule. The order of rules is generally significant; the mutual order of declarations within a rule is usually not, unless they directly or indirectly set the same property.

Answer (score 2):

There's no rule for how you *should* order it.

There's the rule that later declared rules override matching previously declared rules though. So that should inform your organization. E.g.:

```
div { color: black; }
div { color: red; }
# colors will be red
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the actual rules you're writing for a specific element?

e.g.

```
div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:yellow;
}
```

compared to

```
 div{
     background:yellow;
     height:100px;
     width:100px;
}
```

Both will have exactly the same effect, I'm unsure as to why firebug reorders them into a different order, possible just for consistency. As far as declaration goes, there's no difference.

Personally I always write my rules like so: display, width, height, margin, padding, background, border

Personal preference but keeping them consistence with all rules makes it easier not only for you to read but for others looking at your code as well

Not sure if this is what you were asking but I've experienced firebug reordering like this so thought I'd clear it up

Answer (score 0):

If you want the order to find your css role you can simply right click in css area and choose

> inspect in css panel

it will be orders as you like
if it does not order you can search for the role you want